# View .pptx created with python-pptx in real time

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm creating a report using the python-pptx library. Currently my understanding is that if I would like to make a change to the report using the code I've written, I need to have the pptx file closed, then I can run the code, then open the report again.

Is there a way to see what the changes are or will be in real time, or at least faster than my current method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the pptx rendered as you create it - with python-pptx.

But, depending on platform, you probably could get PowerPoint to reload the .pptx upon re-running your program. (I do this all the time on Mac - when my python-pptx program (md2pptx) saves its input file.)